# Can I run and control GUI application on Linux server remotely from Vista desktop?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, remote-desktop

Can I run and control GUI application on Linux server remotely from Vista desktop?

I rent a server with Ubuntu installed from my provider.
I connect to the server remotely from my Vista machine.

Now I need to run a GUI application (Wireshark) on the server and control it from Vista desktop.
Is it possible?
What is the best way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use [VNC](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC) ([over SSH](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC#Guide%20to%20example%20scenarios)) for this. Run [VNC Server](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers) and Open SSH on the GNU/Linux side and use a VNC client on the windows side (like [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/) or [RealVNC](http://www.realvnc.com/)). Refer to the links for the details.

Answer (score 0):

You can via something called X forwarding.  X is the window server for Linux/UNIX machines, which handles drawing windows.  The programs themselves are clients of the window server.  You can get a few different X servers for Windows, but the easiest to set up is the [XMing](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/) package.  XMing includes XLaunch, which helps you easily set up the connection and then remotely launching Wireshark.

Here's an example of XLaunch:

[image: XLaunch]

Here's an example of what apps running on XMing look like (anything with the orange-and-black X icon is a Linux app running on a remote server):

[image]

If you poke around, you'll be able to find detailed walk-throughs of how to get everything set up.